# Comparação de Vetor independentemente da posição

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>


main(){

    int vetoresIguais= 0;

    int vetor[3] = {10,20,5};

    int vetor1[3]= {20,50,15};

    int i;

    int j;

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){

        for(j = i; j < 3;j++){

            if(vetor[i] == vetor1[i]){

                vetoresIguais++;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("%d",vetoresIguais);
}
```

O resultado desse código é 0,por que ele está comparando o vetor em apenas uma posição,se eu colocar o  valor 20 na primeira posição do primeiro vetor ele diz que tem dois valores iguais,como resolver para que compare todos os valores e dizer quantos valores estão repetidos independente da posiçao ser igual ou não?

(Fiquem a vontade para editar,nunca aprendi kk,sou novo por aqui)

Comment: porque vc precisa também executar os dois comandos `for` para o vetor1, para que procure em cada um dos seus elementos. Seria melhor colocar isso numa function, já aprendeu como fazer isso?

Comment: Na comparação dos vetores, troque o i do vetor1 por j, ficando vetor1[ j ]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Cardinalidade da interseção de dois vetores em C

Dependendo da quantidade de elementos do vetor, outra estratégia mais eficiente talvez deva ser empregada. Aquela abaixo é simples, você percorre cada elemento de um dos vetores e verifica quantas vezes este elemento ocorre no outro vetor. A diferença em relação à resposta anterior é que não exige que os elementos dos vetores sejam distintos (ou seja, podem existir repetições).

A complexidade dele é O(n2), comentado em outra resposta, o que significa que para vetores "grandes", conforme já antecipado, talvez você tenha que buscar outra alternativa. Por exemplo, se um dos vetores é ordenado, então não é necessário percorrer todo ele para localizar um dado valor.

```
for (i = 0, i < 3; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
       if (vetor[i] == vetor1[j]) {
         totalComponentesIguais++;
       }
    }
}
```

**IMPORTANTE**: esta solução não exige que os elementos dos vetores sejam distintos.

Answer (score 4):

A maneira correta de comparar 2 vetores é pegar na posiçao i do 1º vetor e comparar com todas as posiçoes do 2º vetor.

```
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        if(vetor[i] == vetor1[j]){
            vetoresIguais++;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Este algoritmo é O(N^2), provavelmente existe uma solução mais rapida, mas esta é facil de perceber

---

Ex:

V1 `|10,5,2|`

V2 `|5,6,10|`

Pegamos nos elementos do **V1** e comparamos com todos do **V2**

> 1º iteração: 10 é igual a 5? Não (i=0, j=0)
>
> 2º iteração: 10 é igual a 6? Não (i=0, j=1)
>
> 3º iteração: 10 é igual a 10? Sim (i=0, j=2)

*Depois pegamos no 5 e fazemos o mesmo*

> 1º iteração: 5 é igual a 5? Sim(i=1, j=0)
>
> break (paramos o ciclo do J e seguimos para a proxima iteraçao de I)

*Pegamos no 2*

> 1º iteração: 2 é igual a 5? Não (i=2, j=0)
>
> 2º iteração: 2 é igual a 6? Não (i=2, j=1)
>
> 3º iteração: 2 é igual a 10? Não (i=2, j=2)

...etc

Answer (score 2):

Reajustando seu codigo:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

int vetor[3] = {10,20,5};
int vetor1[3]= {20,50,15};
int i, j, vetoresIguais;

for(i = 0, vetoresIguais = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        if(vetor[i] == vetor1[j])
        {
            vetoresIguais++;
        }
    }
}

printf("%d",vetoresIguais);

return 0;
}
```

A variavel vetoresIguais seria melhor nomeada como elementosIguais.

Comment: O problema, conforme apresentado inicial, persiste nesta solução.